# how to show only natural numbers on axes in recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I've to build a concentration curve with data set ranging from (0,100) ,including fractional values and have to display only natural numbers on axes. how can it be done?

Comment: Please can you post what have you tried?

Answer (score 6):

Try this prop on both the x and y axes' components:

```
<XAxis
    allowDecimals={false}
/>
```